# Is it possible to get variables with get_defined_vars() but for the actual running script?

Tags: php, variables, scope, defined

I'm trying to create a function to get all user-defined variables for, selectively, unsetting them before the script actually finishes. In order to get all used variables, you must use the `get_defined_vars()` function PHP provides you with, but it has a caveat (for me, at least...): it only works in the scope it's actually called.

I would like to, ideally, encapsulate it in a function inside my framework core namespace, which is `\Helpers\Core` so the function would be `\Helpers\Core\getVariables()`.

Actually, my code looks like this:

```
foreach (array_diff(array_keys(get_defined_vars()), ["_COOKIE", "_ENV", "_FILES", "_GET", "_POST", "_REQUEST", "_SERVER", "_SESSION", "argc", "argv", "GLOBALS", "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA", "http_response_header", "ignore", "php_errormsg"], ["page"]) as $variable) {
    unset($$variable);
}
```

Basically, it tries to automate variable selection by:

- getting all variable names with `array_keys(get_defined_vars())`
- defining a set of reserved or system-wide variables like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER` and so on
- providing which of your used variables are preserved (in this example, `$page`)

The problem is I would like not to place this code every place I want to get rid of some variables at. Ideally, I would like to be able to define this as a function and automate its use, but... is there a way to accomplish this but in the current script you call the function from?

Comment: Use `$GLOBAL` to get variables in global scope and pass result of `get_defined_vars` as argument to your function.

Comment: maybe you can store in the session or cookie?

Comment: That's what I had in mind... a function to insert some variable names into `$_SESSION` so instead of the third member being `["page"]` (like in the example above), it could be automated by specifying it with something like `\Helpers\Core\getVariables()` or similar. I wanted to avoid performing more steps than actually necessary, but maybe it's the only 'guaranteed' way for it to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$GLOBALS` instead of `get_defined_vars()` to access global scope and to unset global variables:

```
$non_user_vars = ["_COOKIE", "_ENV", "_FILES", "_GET", "_POST", "_REQUEST", 
                  "_SERVER", "_SESSION", "argc", "argv", "GLOBALS",
                  "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA", "http_response_header",
                  "ignore", "php_errormsg"];

$safe_user_vars = ["page"];

$all_vars = array_keys($GLOBALS);

$user_vars = array_diff($all_vars, $non_user_vars, $safe_user_vars);

foreach($user_vars as $variable) {
    unset($GLOBALS[$variable]);
}
```

Quick caveats to this approach:

1. to make it cleaner, I defined the arrays first. This could result in them getting into your `$user_vars` array (thought it shouldn't if they are not global) so defend against that to avoid throwing an error or other consequences.
2. Your array of non-user variables is not exhaustive, as when I tested the above, I still got:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [2] => HTTP_ENV_VARS
       [6] => HTTP_POST_VARS
       [8] => HTTP_GET_VARS
       [10] => HTTP_COOKIE_VARS
       [12] => HTTP_SERVER_VARS
       [14] => HTTP_POST_FILES
       [16] => test
       [17] => non_user_vars
   )
   ```

If you don't want to guess which is pre-defined or visible at runtime, maybe there could be an initial call to the `\Helpers\Core\getVariables()` that gets the list of variables and stores them statically so your `array_diff` just needs to diff the initial list with the list at the end to know what is user-defined.

Comment: Ok, now that's a different story. I didn't got the purpose for $GLOBALS until I ran your example. Sorry for the confusion and thank you very much for the hint. Now the method works perfectly! I owe you a beer :)